# CloudKit CKReference List

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckreference

So I hava record that contains a field which is an CKReference List.

Now I would like to fetch all referenced(by this list of CKReferences) records(from another type) in batch.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you have a record "Company" and they have a CKReference List field named "Employees".

Doing the fetch for the Company is easy but once you have the companyRecord, you now want to fetch its Employees. You can do it like this:

```
//first you need to create an array of employee record IDs
var employeeRecordIds = [CKRecordID]()
for employeeReference in companyRecord["Employees"] as! [CKReference] {
    employeeRecordIds.append(employeeReference.recordID)
}
//now you can fetch those employees
var fetchOperation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: employeeRecordIds)
fetchOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = {
    records, error in
    if error != nil {
        print("\(error!)")
    } else {
        for (recordId, record) in records {
            print("\(record)")
        }
    }
}
CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(fetchOperation)
```

Comment: Why not give an example with back references if that's what is encouraged by Apple?

Comment: I removed the note about back referencing since it has nothing to do with the code and what's being asked (fetching). Not sure why I had that in there to begin with, it was just confusing.